# tracing the biggest path of an array of numbers that looks like pyramid

Tags: php

I need to create a function to find the maximum total in a triangle also an array of randomize numbers that showing the Positions.

I have done following:

```
    $number=array();
    $level = $_POST['line'];
    for ($y = 1; $y <= $level; $y ++)
    {
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $y; $x ++)
        {
            $number[$y][$x] = rand(1,9);    
        }
    }

    $path=maxPathSum($number,$level);
    var_dump($path);
}
function maxPathSum($tri, $m) 
{ 
    for ( $i = $m - 1; $i > 0; $i--) 
    {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) 
        { 
            if ($tri[$i + 1][$j] > $tri[$i + 1][$j + 1]) 
            {
                $tri[$i][$j] += $tri[$i + 1][$j];
                $pos=array("x" => $i , "y" => $j);
            }
            else
            {
                $tri[$i][$j] += $tri[$i + 1][$j + 1];
                $pos=array("x" => $i+1 , "y" => $j+1); 
            }
        } 
        $path[]=$pos;
    } 
    $path[]=array("x"=>1,"y"=>1);
    var_dump($path);
    return $triangle[1][1];
}
```

My outputs:

```
{ [1]=> array(1) { [1]=> int(8) } [2]=> array(2) { [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(9) } [3]=> array(3) { [1]=> int(9) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(6) } } array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> int(3) ["y"]=> int(3) } [1]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> int(2) ["y"]=> int(2) } [2]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> int(1) ["y"]=> int(1) } } int(23)
```

Comment: Well, what is this code supposed to do? Any sample input and output?

Comment: it need to give the Positions of longest path 
Also x=row
        y=column
actually it give me the maximum of the maximum path but i need to register a tracing

Comment: Can you give any sample input and output?

Comment: Input 3 
Output
array(3) { [1]=> array(1) { [1]=> int(8) } [2]=> array(2) { [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(9) } [3]=> array(3) { [1]=> int(9) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(6) } } 
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> int(3) ["y"]=> int(3) } [1]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> int(2) ["y"]=> int(2) } [2]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> int(1) ["y"]=> int(1) } } int(23)

Comment: Could you please add this into your post by editing with a proper alignment?

Comment: Their is a lot of algorithms for the exact same thing but with matrix, you should be able to adapt it for trees. The idea is just to create another tree with the same dimension than the processed one, each node equals to processed tree same node + maximum between each nodes able to reach this one. If i got some times I post you something

Answer (score 0):

i made it like this :)

```
function maxPathSum($triangle, $m) 
{ 
    $clone_array=$triangle;
    for ( $i = $m - 1; $i > 0; $i--) 
    {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) 
        { 
            if ($triangle[$i + 1][$j] > $triangle[$i + 1][$j + 1]) 
            {
            $clone_array[$i][$j] += $clone_array[$i + 1][$j];
            }
            else
            {
                $clone_array[$i][$j] += $clone_array[$i + 1][$j + 1];
            }
       } 
   } 
$pos=1;
$position=1;
$pathway=array();
$pathway[]= array($triangle[1][1]) ;
for( $x = 1 ; $x < $m ; $x++ )
{   
    for($position = $pos ; $position < $pos + 1 ; $position++)
    {
        if($clone_array[$x+1][$position] > $clone_array[$x+1][$position+1])
        {
            $pathway[]=array($triangle[$x+1][$position]);
            $pos=$position;
        }
        else
        {
            $pathway[]=array($triangle[$x+1][$position+1]);
            $pos = $position + 1 ;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return $pathway;
```

}